# How to use Join with "OR" condition in Laravel query builder

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-8, laravel-query-builder

I want to check conditions based on two tables. I have two columns common in both the table. While registering a User I assign "Org1" or "Org2" or Both the values to registered user, now when that user login, I want user should see details only of assigned "org". If I have assigned "Org1" as "ab" then he must be able to see all records from predictions where "CurrOrg1" is "ab", If I have assigned values in "Org1" and "Org2" then it must match both columns and fetch only matched records or if nothing is assigned it should load all the records.

Here is my controller code and Query:

```
else
            {
                $loged_user =Auth::user();
                $user= DB:: table('users')
                    ->select('id','Org1','Org2','email');                         
                $data1 = DB:: table('predictions')
                        ->join('users',function($join){
                            $join->on('users.Org1','=','predictions.CurrOrg1');
                            $join->on('users.Org2','=','predictions.CurrOrg2');
                            })
                        ->where('users.email',$loged_user->email)
                        ->select('predictions.id','predictions.EmployeeNumber','predictions.Role','predictions.Region','predictions.CurrOrg1','predictions.CurrOrg2','predictions.RiskZone','predictions.Probablity','predictions.Rating','predictions.Feedback','predictions.Gender','predictions.CurrOrg3','predictions.CurrOrg4','predictions.CurrOrg5','predictions.ProfessionalClassification','predictions.Local_Expat','predictions.EmployeeRoleSeniority','predictions.FeedRisklevel','predictions.Feedinfluencers','predictions.Action','predictions.Fname','predictions.Lname','predictions.Avgweekhr');

                $data = $data1->get();
            }

            return datatables()->of($data)
            ->addColumn('Feedback', function($data)
```

With the above query I am able to fetch record matched in both columns but not able to get or condition. Any suggestion to figure this out would be really helpful.
Thanks

Comment: you can use `orOn` instead of `on`

Comment: This gives all records if I assign both "Org1" and "Org2" to user...if both values is assigned it should use "and" condition and display only records matched with both the columns